# Macro whitespace

Tags: c, malloc

See the below code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MALLOC(n) malloc(n)
int main(void) {
    int *x = MALLOC (sizeof(int) * 10);
    x[0] = 20;x[9] =200;
    printf("%d %d\n",x[0],x[9]);
    return 0;
}
```

I should be calling `MALLOC(sizeof(int) * 10)` right? Since the macro should match the call. Even if I call `MALLOC (sizeof(int) * 10)` I get the same output is this undefined behavior? Or am I missing something?

Is the space after `MALLOC` in the latter call just ignored?

> The standard says when we call a macro its exact textual
>   representation is replaced isn't the case here?

Comment: So... what is your problem? The output is "20 200" what more do you need?

Comment: Apart from missing a cast to `int*`, I don't see where the problem is. What UB are you referring to? Why are you using this macro anyway?

Comment: @Eregrith , I believe Gopi is asking how the macro is called even when there is a space after `MALLOC`.

Comment: @Groo , The cast to `int*` is not required. See [this](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @CoolGuy Exactly you are right..

Comment: (white)spaces are irrelevant

Comment: @Eregrith How is macro expansion happening here?

Comment: @Gopi well the preprocessor sees the macro MALLOC followed by parentheses so it replaces it with what you've `#defined`. This is simply a bit of "syntax freedom"

Comment: @CoolGuy: right, sorry, I confused C with C++.

Comment: @PeterMiehle The standard says when we call a macro its exact textual representation is replaced isn't the case here?

Comment: I cannot say about modern C compilers, but in days gone by, a macro invocation would not compile if there was a space between the macro name and the opening paren

Comment: @user3629249, yes for the `#define` there should be no space before the `()`. Otherwise it could not distinguish the definition of a functional macro from one that just has `()` in the expansion. For the macro *invocation* all of that is irrelevant.

Answer (score 8):

The "whitespace-rule" is important, but only for *function-like* macro definition, not the actual invocation.

In other words there is no difference between:

```
int *x = MALLOC(sizeof(int) * 10);
```

and

```
int *x = MALLOC (sizeof(int) * 10);
```

but no-whitespace is crucial in:

```
#define MALLOC(n) malloc(n)
```

as the following:

```
#define MALLOC (n) malloc(n)
```

defines *object-like* macro `MALLOC` that takes no parameters.